# ui-bootstrap dropdown show alert and disable dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have ui-bootstrap down which shows 4 options in the dropdown as shown below:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div id="btnDate{{$index+1}}" ng-click="btnDateClick($index+1, clientEMAR,$event)" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-menu style="margin 0; padding: 0; height: 55px; width: 50px;">click me </div>                                       
<ul id="btnDropDownList{{$index+1}}" ng-click="isOpen = true" class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
       <li class="bg-success"><a ng-click="green(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Administered</a></li>
       <li class="bg-danger"><a ng-click="red(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Refused / Missed</a></li>
       <li class="bg-warning"><a ng-click="orange(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Medication Held</a></li>
       <li class="bg-info"><a ng-click="details(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Details</a></li>
       </ul></div>
```

In few of the cases I want to check few properties of object clientEMAR and then display alert and want to return without showing dropdown options.

I have used $event.stopPropogation() as per my little knoweldge but did not work for me.

```
$scope.btnDateClick = function (index, clientEMAR,$event) {

if (clientEMAR.sched_id == 0) 
{
   alert("Can't edit empty schedule dates.");
   $event.stopPropagation();
   return;
} 
}
```

Please help.

Edited Solution:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<div id="btnDate{{$index+1}}" ng-click="btnDateClick($index+1, clientEMAR,$event)" ng-disabled="disabledDD" class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-menu style="margin 0; padding: 0; height: 55px; width: 50px;">click me </div>                                       
<ul id="btnDropDownList{{$index+1}}" ng-click="isOpen = true" class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0">
   <li class="bg-success"><a ng-click="green(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Administered</a></li>
   <li class="bg-danger"><a ng-click="red(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Refused / Missed</a></li>
   <li class="bg-warning"><a ng-click="orange(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Medication Held</a></li>
   <li class="bg-info"><a ng-click="details(clientEMAR, $index+1)">Details</a></li>
</ul></div>

$scope.btnDateClick = function (index, clientEMAR,$event) {

if (clientEMAR.sched_id == 0) 
{
alert("Can't edit empty schedule dates.");
$scope.disabledDD = true;
return;
} 
}
```

Just added a flag which set disable property of dropdown toggle to on/off and it worked like magic.

Comment: `preventDefault()` is probably the method you're thinking of, but i'm not sure it will work

Comment: Tried that too..but no help.

Comment: Added a solution in the Edits.

Comment: post it as a solution, if someone will find it useful it's free cred